# How can I create multiple joins, with the same tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to create a query which will display ALL employees, ALL the training that each employee has taken, and ALL the training that is available (ApplicableTraining) to be taken, even if the employee has not taken it.

Sample Applicable Training:

```
WHMIS
First Aid
CPR
Propane
TDG
```

Sample EmployeeTraining

```
Sam | WHMIS | 05/03/2011 |05/03/2012
Sam | First AID | 06/09/2010 | 06/09/2011
Sam | CPR | 05/03/2011 | 05/03/2012
Sam | Propane | 12/03/2015| 12/03/2018
```

Desired Results

```
Sam | WHMIS | 05/03/2011 |05/03/2012
Sam | First AID | 06/09/2010 | 06/09/2011
Sam | CPR | 05/03/2011 | 05/03/2012
Sam | Propane | 12/03/2015| 12/03/2018
Sam | TDG | |
```

[http://imgur.com/jMU6fgt][1]

When I try to create these joins, it tells me I am trying to create ambiguous joins.

I then tried to create a query that is a leftjoin & union of ALL employees and the training they have taken. So that the resulting table is Employee|Training|Datetaken|Expiry

```
SELECT ApplicableTraining.AppTraining, 
EmployeeTraining.Employee, 
EmployeeTraining.DateTaken, 
EmployeeTraining.Expiry

FROM ApplicableTraining LEFT JOIN EmployeeTraining ON ApplicableTraining.AppTraining = EmployeeTraining.Training;
```

With this query, I was trying to create another query that leftjoins the applicable training (list of all training available) to this query. However, it is not returning any training courses that the employee has not taken. Ex: if I haven't taken CPR training, I want a record to show up as  " ME|CPR| | |

Comment: Edit your question and include the query along with the error message you are getting.

Comment: The query you posted will not return any values for the "Employee" when the Training is TDG, therefore on your second pass, when you try to do a left join to this query on the employee field, you will get an ambiguous join as there will be null values in your first query's [Employee] field.

Comment: Your left join looks OK. Show the full query that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to try a CROSS JOIN between Employee and ApplicableTraining.  Then left join this query to all the training results queries as it appears from the graphic that both tables are left joined to all of them.  This should return you every employee and all training available and show the training results where they exist.

I assume you'd want to union together your training results first, though, to avoid repeating rows.

Comment: Not quite familiar with CROSS JOIN,  but what would I join on between Employee and ApplicableTraining? Applicable Training is just a list of courses available. Employee is just a list of names, ID and phone numbers.

Comment: A [cross join](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6#bmcross) doesn't link on anything at all. So you would return each Employee combined with each ApplicableTraining in every combination.  This ensures all employees and all training that is available are returned.  From this you could left join to find available EmployeeTraining.  Note that you'd have to alias ApplicableTraining.id or Employee.id first before performing the final join.